# Magneto diagnosis for old chainsaw engine

Tags: ignition-coil

I'm attempting the restoration of an old Pioneer 620.
Rotating the flywheel manually doesn't produce any spark.

I disassembled the ignition assembly, which is a Wico FW 2542.
The circuit is very simple. There are 2 coils in 1 package, mounted on the ferrite core.
Out of the primary comes a thin cable which goes to the points, to the kill switch and to a capacitor. The other pole of capacitor, points and killswitch go to ground. The thick cable out of the secondary goes to the spark plug.

The coils package is a Wico X11180 and the capacitor is a Wico X11181.
I can't find replacement points but I think they're still good.

There's continuity on both primary and secondary.

- Primary resistance: about 1.5 Ohm
- Secondary resistance: about 5 KOhm. Is that normal?

I'm not entirely sure but I think that the capacitor across the points is faulty. I tried to disconnect it but it still doesn't work.

I also tried to test the coils using a battery and it did not work. The setup was a bit wonky, but there was continuity so it should have sparked when I opened the circuit on the primary, but it did not. Actually there's always 0 voltage across the secondary when the current accross the primary varies.

So.. is the thing toast? Is there something else I didn't consider?

Questions:

- is it paramount that the flywheel is inserted all the way? it's been a pain to extract it from the shaft.. so I don't wanna tighten it down until I'm confident it can work and the ignition is phased correctly.
- do this kind of ignition only produce electricity when the flywheel is turning above a given speed? (I'll try again when I sort out the cord and pulley mechanism)
- the capacitor is only there to prevent sparks between the points, but isn't strictly necessary, right?
- what would be an appropriate size for a replacement capacitor?
- could this work as a replacement for the coils? https://www.ebay.it/itm/374032603290 how do I know how many windings I need..?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!